# Unable to create an executable jar file and manifest.txt

Tags: java, jar, compilation

I am trying to create an executable jar file. I have a Test.java file and after running this command:

```
javac Test.java
```

I now have two files: Test.java and Test.javac

Now, to create my JAR file, I did this:

```
jar cvf Test.jar Test.class
```

However, after executing the jar:

```
java -jar Test.jar
```

I get this message:

```
no main manifest attribute, in Test.jar
```

So then I read I needed a manifest file, so I did this:

```
jar cvfm Test.jar manifest.txt *.class
```

But I got this message:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: manifest.txt (No such file or directory)
```

Now, I am a bit confused because I don't know what I have done wrong. My two questions are:

1) How to properly create an executable jar file?

2) What is a manifest file?

**EDIT**

My direction structure is as follows:

Test/src/me/pablo/main/

Within that folder I have: Test.java, Test.class, Manifest.txt, and the jar files.

However, when I run commands, I do it within Test/src/me/pablo/main/ so I don't have to use long addresses.

Comment: Can you try placing the manifest file infront of  the jar file  "jar cvfm manifest.txt Test.jar  *.class"

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov I get this error: "java.io.IOException: invalid header field"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Manifest file is an archive indicanting the application entry point. It must be included in your jar. It is required to properly create an executable Jar file. Is in this file where you indicate which is your Main class (the class with your main method):

> Main-Class: MyPackage.MyClass

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) is the documentation about it.

There is a command that creates a Manifest file for you:

> jar cfe YourJar.jar yourPackage.YourClass yourPackage/YourClass.class

Comment: How can I generate one successfully?

Comment: First create a text file named Manifest.txt with the following contents:

`Main-Class: MyPackage.MyClass`

Then create a JAR file named MyJar.jar by entering the following command:

`jar cfm MyJar.jar Manifest.txt MyPackage/*.class`

Comment: Ok, created the manifest file. added the main class in the first line. Then I ran: jar cfm MyJar.jar Manifest.txt *.class. The jar file still says there is no manifest file. The manifest file says:   Main-Class: me.pablo.main.Test

Comment: Try executing the next command: `jar cfe YourJar.jar yourPackage.YourClass yourPackage/YourClass.class`

Comment: I ran it an it says: "me.pablo.main/Test.class : no such file or directory" so I just ran it without the yourPackage/ and it built the jar. However, the jar when run says: Could not find or load main class Test.java

Comment: Please edit your post adding your directory structure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152572/discussion-between-juan-carlos-mendoza-and-pablo).